# Fish while & if with a pipeline condition : Command substitutions not allowed

Tags: fish

Consider this brief conversation with fish:

`while (echo d | mail) ; sleep 1 ; end`

```
fish: Command substitutions not allowed
while (echo d | mail) ; sleep 1 ; end
      ^
```

how can I correct my while loop?

More generally: do I understand right that the problem is something like : the while CONDITION is a command, but fish only allows `(command substitution)` for *parameters* to a command, not the command itself?

So I think my question for both `if` and `while` could be : how do I write a pipeline as the CONDITION?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be written simply as:

```bash
while echo d | mail; sleep 1; end
```

In fish, as in other shells, command substitutions takes the output of the inner command, and uses it as arguments to the outer command. The exit status is discarded, which is why fish disallows them as the condition in loops.

Comment: Thanks. But it seems to me that bash doesn't discard the exit status? `if (which nosuchfile > /dev/null ) ; then echo yes $? ; else echo no $? ; fi ` takes the no branch whereas (which which) takes the yes branch

Comment: That `(which)` in bash denotes a *subshell*. It just means to run the thing in a new process (which in this case is most likely useless). In fish, `(which)` would mean what `$(which)` means in bash, a "command substitution".

Comment: Fish isn't bash, see https://fishshell.com/docs/current/fish_for_bash_users.html